# "GodMode" folder contents c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shell, enumeration

I am currently building an application that will need to use all of the Control Panel's shortcuts which can be found in "`shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`" aka GodMode folder.

However, when I try to access the folder through code, I get no result. This also happens when I try to enumerate the files using the command prompt (**using 'dir'**).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why will it need to use all the shortcuts? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: God wasn't involved, it is a virtual shell folder, not a real one.  Avoid religious google hits by querying for "enumerate virtual shell folder".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The God Mode is implemented in the Windows Explorer Shell. If you look at it at the file system level it's just an ordinary folder with a peculiar name. That's why you won't see anything special in it when reading it as a directory in code. If you look at it with the command prompt it's the same - just a plain empty folder with a peculiar name.

You won't be able to access the shortcuts through the file system API, so you have to look for an API that exposes the control panel contents instead.